# Create javascript variable with mixed direction language and bolding for html

Tags: javascript, html, right-to-left

I am writing code in javascript that will be exported to html. My issue is that my variables contain strings that must be partially bolded, however the language of the string is a right-to-left language (Hebrew), so when I try to put in the "" or "**" in the string, it moves the text and does not bold the right words. For example, I need to create:**

**זה **מבחן and **זה **עוד מבחן

```
var test = ["זה <b>מבחן<b>, "<b>זה עוד<b> מבחן"]
```

but my html output in html becomes: זהמבחן and **עוד מבחן **זה. It is also not possible to just simply reverse the bolding, because this does not work.

How can I properly bold parts of right-to-left text in the strings of a javascript variable so the html output follows the proper bolding pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To properly bold parts of right-to-left text in the strings of a JavaScript variable, you can use the HTML tag  with the CSS property direction: rtl; to ensure that the text is displayed correctly. Here's an example:

```
var test = ['<span style="direction: rtl;">זה <b>מבחן</b></span>', '<span style="direction: rtl;"><b>זה עוד</b> מבחן</span>'];
```

In this example, the  tag is used to wrap the text that needs to be bolded, and the direction: rtl; CSS property is applied to ensure that the text is displayed correctly. The bolded text is then enclosed in the  tag as usual.
When you output this variable in HTML, the text will be displayed correctly with the bolded parts in the right place.

Comment: One more question: in this fomat, how would you bold part of a word but not the entire word. I try this using <b> but it puts a space between the two parts of the word. Is there a way to keep the word together but bold a couple of letters?

Comment: you can use the <span> tag to apply bolding to specific parts of a word without breaking up the word.

 <span style="font-weight:bold;">